# Mule SFTP File Listener

Tags: java, mule, sftp

I have a question about mule.

I have a SFTP Component that moves file to local directory every end of month by Quartz component.

but when the file upcoming to the SFTP at the middle of month.

I want to move it at a time, i don't want to wait until end of month.

i need something depends on event, listening files like service or something like this.

If Is there any configuration can help me.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're after. Maybe an example would help?

Comment: @DavidDossot Sorry, i updated my Question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `<composite-source>` as your flow source and place inside of it both a `quartz` endpoint and, say, an `http` endpoint.

That way you'll be able to trigger manually (over HTTP) the same flow that gets triggered monthly by Quartz.